# Found not working imports: QtMultimedia is not installed

Tags: javascript, windows, qt, qml

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtMultimedia 5.6
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    width: 640
    height: 360

    Camera {
        id: camera

        imageProcessing.whiteBalanceMode: CameraImageProcessing.WhiteBalanceFlash

        exposure {
            exposureCompensation: -1.0
            exposureMode: Camera.ExposurePortrait
        }

        flash.mode: Camera.FlashRedEyeReduction

        imageCapture {
            onImageCaptured: {
                photoPreview.source = preview  // Show the preview in an Image
            }
        }
    }

    VideoOutput {
        source: camera
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus : visible // to receive focus and capture key events when visible
    }

    Image {
        id: photoPreview
    }
}
```

I just uinstalled Qt 5.5.1 and installed Qt 5.6 (but above is the new project created in Qt 5.6). I added
`QT += multimedia`
in my pro file. I use MSVC 2013 (as alway when using Qt), Windows 7. It builds program and when I click Run, it works, although it shows in Application Output: 3x failed to access to the graph builder. I could ignore it, but I am not able to access to Design mode ("Cannot open this QML document beacuse of an error in the QML file"). Could you help me to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Copying the missing module manually to
   `%QT_CREATOR_INSTALLATION%\bin\qml\` can solve your problem. This is
   because Qt Creator, here in Design mode, only import modules from
   `%QT_CREATOR_INSTALLATION%\bin\qml\` folder.
2. After copying, you may or may not face another question. The module
   that you copied may not work in the design mode. Because the module
   must be well designed and tested before it can be used in the design
   mode. In fact, the module must be marked as `designersupported` in
   it's `qmldir` file.

`QtMultimedia` is not installed in the `%QT_CREATOR_INSTALLATION%\bin\qml\` folder and not marked as `designersupported`. So, you can't use it in the Design mode.